# Question about mathematical logic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Let say that you think you have 10 dollars in your pocket and you find out that you have two more dollars than what you thought you had, so you have 12 dollars. But what does it mean to say that you have two more dollars than twice what you thought you had?

Comment: ...that you have 22 dollars?

Comment: so you have twice the proper amount and two more dollars

Comment: Yes, that is what the usual interpretation would be.

Comment: ???? What the heck is "the proper amount"?  Proper for what?  I don't have the slightest idea what you are talking about.  but if you have 10 dollars than don't you have ten dollars?  If 10 dollars is 2 more than the "proper amoutn" (whatever that means) then isnt the proper amount 8 dollars?  And if you have 2 more dollars than twice the proper amount doesn't that mean the proper amount is 4 dollars?  What the heck are you talking about?

Comment: proper amount is 10 dollars. Basically You think that you have 10 dollars which is the proper amount then you check your pocket and you find out that you have 2 more dollars than twice what you thought you had. My question is that when we say that we have two more dollars, we imply that we have 2 dollars plus what we thought we had.

Comment: This question is more about the english language and the interpretation of sentences (possibly sentences that depend on context for their interpretation). When you say "2 more dollars" the interpretation is dependent on the context...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836771/question-about-diophantine-equations

Answer (score 0):

Let $t$ be the number of dollars that you thought you had.

(two more dollars) than (twice what you thought you had)

(twice what you thought you had) + (two more dollars)

you have $2t + 2$ dollars